# Deduce template parameter from concept

Tags: c++, clang, c++-concepts

I'm learning templates and concepts. I'm trying to make a concept for types that are derived from a class, but this class is a template.

```
template<typename T>
struct CAA{};

template<typename T, typename T2>
concept DerivedFromAA = requires() {std::derived_from<CAA<T2>,T>;};
```

Is it possible to use such concept in a function without having to explicitly tell it the template type of the class? Is my idea wrong on how to define such concept?

```
template<typename T>
void conceptTestFunc(DerivedFromAA<T> auto& aa)
{
}

//...

CAA<int> aa;
conceptTestFunc<int>(aa); // Without having to tell it "int"
```

(I'm compiling this with Clang.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A template is not a type.

So if `CAA` is a template, then `CAA<int>` would be a type.

A type can't be derived from a template, only from another type. This means that the check has to be done on the type, not the template.

If you on the other hand want to deduce the inner type of `aa`, that can be done.

```
#include <concepts>

template<typename T>
struct CAA{};

template<typename T>
struct CBB{};

template<typename T, typename T2>
concept DerivedFromAA = std::derived_from<CAA<T2>,T>;

template<template <typename> typename Outer, typename T>
requires DerivedFromAA<Outer<T>, T>
void conceptTestFunc(Outer<T>& aa)
{
}

int main() {
    CAA<int> aa;
    conceptTestFunc(aa);
    CBB<int> bb;
    conceptTestFunc(bb); // This fails
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! Could you please tell me or point me toward any read material what happens in those two lines before declaring `void conceptTestFunc`. This especially: `template<template <typename> typename Outer, typename T>`

Comment: It's called [template template parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters). There's a section in the link with more details.

Answer (score 1):

You might do

```
template<typename T>
concept DerivedFromAA = requires(T t) {[]<typename U>(CAA<U>&){}(t);};

static_assert(DerivedFromAA<CAA<int>>);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/T7qfvPMff)

gcc dislikes lambda in requires, so you might create dummy helper function outside.