# Single template parameter concept type constraint for multiple parameter template type

Tags: c++, templates, constraints, variadic-templates, c++-concepts

I have a custom templated class type:

```
template<T1, T2, T3>
class MyType{
   public:
     using value_type = T1;
     value_type val();
   private:
     T1 val;
}
```

I would like to make a simple concept type:

```
template<>
concept = MyTypeTemplateType
```

in order to write

```
template<MyTypeTemplateType>
MyType myFunc(T arg){
    //some stuff. e.g.
    return MyType{std::abs(arg.val())};
};
```

}

What I have so far is:

```
template<typename... Ts>
concept MyTypeTemplateType= requires(MyType<Ts...> arg) {
                       arg.val();
                   };
```

However, when I do:

```
MyType<int, float, float> myVal{5};
auto myVal2 myFunc(myVal);
```

I get a compiler error:

> In substitution of 'template  requires  MyTypeTemplateType T myFunc(T) [with T = MyType<int, float, float>]';
> required for the satisfaction of 'MyTypeTemplateType' [with T = MyType<int, float, float>]
> in requirements with 'MyType<Ts ...> arg' [with Ts = {int, float, float}]
> wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 3)

I would need to decompose `T` into a template pack `Ts` it seems...

Any ideas? I'm fairly new to concepts and template parameters packs.

Comment: There are so many typos in your description of the problem that I can't understand what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: @康桓瑋 My apologies. The answer by [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74731492/4449225) is in-line with what I'm trying to achieve. I was hoping to do it without using a type traits approach with template specialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you might create a traits:

```
template <typename T>
struct IsMyType : std::false_type {};

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
struct IsMyType<MyType<T1, T2, T3>> : std::true_type {};
```

and then

```
template <typename T>
concept MyTypeTemplateType = IsMyType<T>::value;
```

Comment: Works. Any way of using `requires` instead of template specialization?

Comment: I see one way, something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67476096/2684539).